# Writing to all txt files in directory and in the sub dirs

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

so I'm not a coding student or anything. I'm doing this for a personal project that I wanted to do. I've spent hours with multiple codes trying to figure this out and I'm pretty close. **I want to pick a directory, and then write to all the text files in every single sub directory it has. I don't want to list out every single subdirectory, as they will be increasing in size over time and I don't want to have to edit this code.**

When this runs, it will write to ever text file in the directory, but the sub directories say  java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

**The files do exist, and it's on my desktop so access shouldn't be an issue**

I'm completely stumped as to what do do now. If I was actually a programming student I bet this wouldn't be an issue, but I'm not so yeah. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String dirName = "C:\\Users\\Zed\\Desktop\\Test";
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for(File file : files){



    String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    if (s.contains("w = 64")) {


    s = s.replace("w = 64", "w = 87.04"); 
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file)) {
    fw.write(s);            
    fw.close();



    } catch (FileSystemException e) {
        System.out.println("Access Denied");




            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Success! Thank you to all who tried to help, I really appreciate it. This is the little bit of code I needed to make this work!**

```
String[] extensions = new String[] { "ini"};
    List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);
    //File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for(File file : files){

    if (file.isDirectory ()) continue;
```

Comment: Gee I wonder what `AccessDeniedException` means

Comment: `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` does not mean the files don't exist. It means you don't have permission to create, edit or read files in the directory.

Comment: I understand that, but the fact is I've created multiple directories to test this and I continue to get the AccessDeniedException. I should not be getting this, because I have full access.

Comment: Are any of the files open in another application when you try to run your program? Also you may want to change your `catch` statement to make a call to `e.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println("Access Denied")`, it gives a more descriptive explanation.

Comment: No there is nothing open except chrome and eclipse. No files, no folders, just nothing. Another thing I forgot to mention, the catch function doesn't seem to work. Like it doesn't print anything out, even when I change it to `e.printStackTrace()`

It says the error is in this line `String s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: Have you iterated over the `File` array `files` and checked that you're getting the expected files? Perhaps your also getting hidden files that you might not have access to.

Comment: Yes. Whenever I put files into `C:\\Users\\Zed\\Desktop\\Test` the program works. However, when I put some into a sub-directory `C:\\Users\\Zed\\Desktop\\Test\\Test5` I started getting the access denied error. 

When I change the code to `String dirName = "C:\\Users\\Zed\\Desktop\\Test\\Test5";` it goes straight to that folder. I would like all sub folders to get written to without having to go through and write them all out (as in sub-directory numbers will increase over time) Hopefully that's what you were asking me haha

Comment: You should do a [google search for "Java Windows Recursive Directory"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Java+Windows+Recursive+Directory&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). The first couple of links provide some valuable information on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have subdirectories in your `dirName` path, then you will be trying to write to them, so check using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
for(File file : files){
   if (file.isDirectory ()) continue;

   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This got rid of my `Access Denied` error. Now it's just not writing to the files within the sub directories. If you have any ideas that would be amazing. I'm going to continue playing around to see if I can get it to work

Comment: If this was in a recursive method, then if you came across a directory, tou could simply recursive into into it.

Comment: Hmm I'm not actually sure if this is a recursive method or not. I don't really know much about coding, sorry. I've spent probably about 5 hours trying to figure this out and the code I have is the best I can come up with